# Issue moving a file and error when unzip

Tags: tar, hidden-files, gzip

Not sure if this is as weird as I see it

But anyway

I'm installing kippo-graph "data visualization tool" on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS but after I download the file which is (kippo.tar.gz) and I move it to other directory it appears as a hidden file...
Then when I run this command to unzip the file

```
tar zxvf kippo-graph-1.2.tar.gz
```

I get this error message

```
tar (child): kippo-graph-1.2.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

how can I solve the problem and proceed with the unzipping process

Comment: What command did you use to move it? Have you tried 'tar xvf .kippo-graph-1.2.tar.gz'?

Comment: Can you do `ls -la | grep kippo` in the directory containing your archive?

Comment: @Seth "mv kippo-graph-0.7.6.tar /var/www"     with/out sudo        and "tar xvf kippo-graph-0.7.6.tar.gz"

Comment: @user1794499 did you change directories to /var/www after moving the file?

Comment: @Seth yup I did but I can not view them?

Comment: You aren't really giving us enough information to tell. We need *full* terminal output.

Comment: @Seth I have included the output in my question..what else you mean by "full terminal output"

Comment: You just gave us clipped output, we need everything the terminal said. The prompt, what you typed in, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have get to answer for this unzipping issue

I used "xzvf kippo-graph-1.3.tar.gz"

and it did the trick everything is fine now

thank you guys for the effort